# How can I start activity with string parameters in appium?

Tags: javascript, android, adb, appium, appium-android

I have activity for tests (which open any activity with parameters) and it works via adb. Here example command for adb:

```
adb shell am start -n "com.xxx.xxx/com.zzz.zzz.ui.test.TestActivity" --es "activity" "com.zzz.zzz.ui.opinion.NotificationScheduledActivity" --es "params" "\[\{name='date',type='date',value='2018-05-12'\},\{name='can_return',type='boolean',value=false\}\]"
```

But I not idea how I should do that this command works via appium (via wd command `startActivity()`).
If I try does like this:

```
this.activity = {
           appPackage: 'com.xxx.xxx',
           appActivity: 'com.zzz.zzz.ui.test.TestActivity',
           optionalIntentArguments: \` --es "activity" "com.zzz.zzz.ui.opinion.NotificationScheduledActivity" --es "params" "\\[\\{name='date',type='date',value='2018-05-22'\\},\\{name='can_return',type='boolean',value=false\\}\\]"\`
return driver.startActivity(activity)
```

its not work (activity try to statr but app crashed immeditary). And in the end appium says that activity never started.
How I should rewrite data in activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Works fine like this:

```
let activity = {
            appPackage: 'com.app.package',
            appActivity: 'com.FakeActivity',
            appWaitActivity: 'com.NeededActivity',
            optionalIntentArguments: ` --es "activity" "com.NeededActivity" --es "params" "\[\{name='date',type='date',value='2018-05-22'\},\{name='can_return',type='boolean',value=false\}\]"`
        };
return driver.startActivity(activity);
```